# Strings before parameter definitions

Tags: php

It seems like PHP allows having strings (like the string `foo` in the example below) before parameters in function definitions.

```
function do_something(foo $param){}
```

Is this some kind of a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some kind of type-safety feature in PHP

If you have

```
class Something {
 public function add(Something $s) { .. }
}

$s = new Something();
$s->add(new stdCLass());
```

This will throw catchable fatal error.

You can see it here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Comment: Seems like a powerful feature. How about return types? Is there a way to specify these too?

Comment: No, hinted return types are not currently implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, In your example you are using type hinting, saying that parameter $param must be an instance of class "foo"

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to define what type is allowed to be passed to the function. If you look at [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#98425) on the PHP.net Function Arguments page you will see that you can define a class to be the type that is allowed.